# Unbinding Right click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have tried following unbind methods to unbind element with class `'.rightclickarea'`.

```
   $('.rightclickarea').unbind();

         $('.rightclickarea').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
             e.preventDefault()
             });
```

But the element is not unbound of the event.So every time I call this method BindBookMarkPopUp() it tries to bind again which is creating a problem.  So is there any way I can Unbind before each binding in jquery. Thanks!

```
function BindBookMarkPopUp() {


$('.rightclickarea').unbind("contextmenu");

$('.rightclickarea').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {

    id = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#current_id").html(id.substring(3));
    $("#current_id").attr("data-type",1);

    var $cmenu = $(".vmenu_bookmark");
    $('<div class="overlay"></div>').css({
        left : '0px',
        top : '0px',
        position : 'absolute',
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%',
        zIndex : '100'
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $cmenu.hide();
    }).bind('contextmenu', function() {
        return false;
    }).appendTo(document.body);
    $(".vmenu_bookmark").css({
        left : e.pageX,
        top : e.pageY,
        zIndex : '101'
    }).show();
    return false;
});

$('.vmenu_bookmark .first_li').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).children().size() == 1) {
        alert("book_marks");

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "vmenu_bookmark") {
            $.colorbox({
                inline : true,
                width : 280,
                height : 120,
                href : "#title_content",
                title : "Enter title for Bookmark"
            });

        }
        $('.vmenu_bookmark').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
    }
});


$('.vmenu_bookmark .second_li').live('click', function() {


    if ($(this).children().size() == 1) {

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "vmenu_project") {

        alert("project_click")
            PopulateProjects();

            $.colorbox({
                inline : true,
                width : 500,
                height : 400,
                title : "",
                href : "#title_content_project"

            });


        }

        $('.vmenu_bookmark').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="vmenu vmenu_bookmark">
            <div class="first_li" id="vmenu_bookmark"><span>Add to Bookmark</span></div>
            <div class="second_li" id="vmenu_project"><span>Add to Project</span></div>
            <div style="display: none;" class="sep_li"></div>

            <div style="display:none;" class="first_li"><span>XYZ</span>
                <div class="inner_li">
                    <span>ABC</span> 
                    <span>PQR</span>
                    <span>MNO</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The question is confusing.  BindBookMarkPopUp unbinds all events, then re-binds the two handlers, so it's working as you describe.  Please describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BrianV   its not unbinding ..... I have noticed this by putting some alerts in my code ....  i get pop ups the number of times its bound.

Comment: @BrianV ...edited my post to include the entire method ..pls have a look at it nw

Comment: Added the HTML code as well

Answer (score 1):

The `unbind` method reverses (removes) a previously bound event handlers. You cannot `unbind` in advance handlers that hasn't been bound yet.

If you wish to unbind a certain event handler, you do that subsequently. For example, in order to unbind all previously bound `contextmenu` events, you can do:

```
$(".rightclickarea").unbind("contextmenu")
```

You can also unbind all previously bounds events of **all types**, just by not providing an argument:

```
$(".rightclickarea").unbind()
```

Finally, if you wish to unbind only a specific event handler, you have two options (which both require you to act differently when first binding):

**Option 1**

You bind your method using a `namespace`, for example:

```
$(".rightclickarea").bind("contextmenu.myUniqueHandler", function() {
   /* your code here */
})
```

And then you can unbind this specific event handler using:

```
$(".rightclickarea").unbind("contextmenu.myUniqueHandler")
```

**Option 2**

You enclose your callback function and store it inside a variable, then pass it to the `bind` method:

```
var myUniqueHandler = function() {
   /* your code here */
}

$(".rightclickarea").bind("contextmenu", myUniqueHandler)
```

Then you unbind it using that said variable:

```
$(".rightclickarea").unbind("contextmenu", myUniqueHandler)
```

---

## Edit:

Going in-depth with your problem (after further clarification) you are actually having issues with `.vmenu_bookmark` firing multiple times at once, after several calls to `BindBookMarkPopUp`.

The problem is that your'e assuming that using `unbind` on `.rightclickarea` will reverse anything that was done (or bound) inside the callback function. It does not.

**When you use `unbind`, you only prevent your bound function from executing any further:**

```
// this will not execute after an unbind:
$('.rightclickarea').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {

    // ....
    // some code
    // ...
    // ..

    // VVV This will not unbind, it will still work. VVV
    $('.vmenu_bookmark .first_li').live('click', function() { 
       /// ...
    })
})
```

Everything you do above, will not reverse after an unbind - including your `.live` / `.bind` calls.

This means that each call to `BindBookMarkPopUp` will add another event handler (`bind`) to `.vmenu_bookmark`, causing them to pile up.

The solution would be to move all of your `.bind()` and `.live()` calls (including `.vmenu_bookmark...` and `.rightclickarea`) to ****outside of the function****.

There is no reason for you to bind multiple times - you only have to do that once.

---

Comment: ...could you please show me an example using my code ..... i dint exactly get ur explanation .....Thanks!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I have edited my post to include all the code .... Basically I am calling the method bindbookmarkpopup method that i mentioned in my post several times .... so each time its called its binding .rightclickarea ...which inturn has a .click function ($('.vmenu_bookmark .second_li').live('click', function() {) ...so this .click function is being executed as many times .rightclickarea is bound which should not happen ...as in i want to unbind all the bound events from .rightclickarea before each bind.... please let me know if you want me to explain more ..thanks for your time

Comment: I have expanded my answer, according to your explanation.